# PWA google login not working with Samsung Internet

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I've a PWA app whose login works with all other browsers except for Samsung Internet

https://github.com/pwa-builder/PWABuilder/issues/4090

More details about the app here

Can someone help out as to what the error could be here for 403 forbidden, I tried debugging it and checking the console but on 403 it gets disconnected